# selecting columns equal to a field in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas DataFrame looks like this:

```
0                   STUN
1                  Webex
2                    PPP
3                MyVideo
4                Icecast
5               PPSTREAM
6                    FTP
7                   SPDY
8     Thunder/Webthunder
9                    IRC
10            CitrixGoTo
11                 FLASH
12               GameKit
13                   RDP
14                IMplus
...
505         unknown
506      BitTorrent
507          ISAKMP
508            HTTP
509       REALMEDIA
510     Silverlight
```

From this I have to select the columns which are equal to HTTP and SSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the isin Series method on a column:

```
df[df[column_name].isin(['HTTP', 'SSH'])]
```

An alternative is to check for either being equal (most likely this will be faster):

```
df[(df[column_name] == 'HTTP') | (df[column_name] == 'SSH'])]
```

Comment: Curious.  How does this answer the question?  I am trying to do a similar thing and df[column_name] is not something built in.  I am really trying to wrack my brain to figure this same problem out.  I need to conditionally select a column based on a value.

Comment: @drewid Looking back, I'm not sure how I inferred what this question was about. But in this answer, `column_name` is one of the columns e.g. 'A', and you want to extract out the rows which have HTTP or SSH in that particular column. However, there's a typo: this should be | rather than &. Does that make sense?